# Rage Datepicker not working on second click

Tags: c#, jquery, date, datepicker

I am Using textboxes.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="From_Date_Txt" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="Date_To_Txt" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

and on the selection of the First textbox, the second textbox limits the date to the selected (from date) and beyond. Dates before the selected date cannot be chosen.

```
 $(function () {
            SetFromDatePicker();
            var dp;
            var dp2;
            var s;
        });

        function SetFromDatePicker() {
            dp = $('#<%=From_Date_Txt.ClientID%>');
            dp.datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
                startDate: '12-12-2010',
                todayHighlight: true,
                language: "en"
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                s = '';
                $(this).blur();
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
                $('.datepicker .today').click();
                s = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_From_Date_Txt').val();
                $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_Date_To_Txt').val('');
                SetFromDatePicker2(s);
            });
        }

        function SetFromDatePicker2(s) {
            dp2 = $('#<%=Date_To_Txt.ClientID%>');
            dp2.datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
                startDate: s,
                todayHighlight: true,
                language: "en"
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                $(this).blur();
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
                $('.datepicker .today').click();
            });
        }
```

If I select 19-05-2017 in the "**From_Date_Txt**" text box the calendar limits me to 19 as the start date. If on second try I update the date to 21-05-2017 in the "**From_Date_Txt**" it still shows me 19 as the start date in the **Date_To_Txt**

```
<script src="../../asset/js/plugins/datapicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="../../asset/css/plugins/datapicker/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: did you debug and check what is the value passed to `SetFromDatePicker2()` when you select the start date second time..

Comment: Yes, I have used alerts and it seems to be getting correct values for the frist time.  But the S value seems to remain the same for the second time.

Comment: can u provide me link to the css and js you have used for calendar.

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js
</br>https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css